# Make links contained in Ajax open in same div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys i'm working on a web app using Jquery mobile and Ajax.
There is a page with a menu on left and when i click on the items it loads some other pages in the right side div.

I'm using Ajax to open other pages in the Jquery Mobile App , the problem is when i click on links in the pages it does not open in the same div. like here:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "sendrequestslist.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
    });
```

How can i open the links in `sendrequestslist.php`  in the same page (in #content div).

Thanks guys , really appreciate the help

Comment: Is the code working? Is it providing any information?

Comment: yes , it loads the page perfectly , i just need the links in that page to open in the same div

Comment: You mean to replace the `url` depending upon the clicks?

Comment: Without seeing all the page its almost impossible to be of any help here!

Comment: well the sendrequestslist.php contains a table and each row has a link , i want to open the content of the link in the same page or div here when i click on them and not opening a new page

Comment: Is expected result for `#content` `html` to be replaced by `html` referenced by `a` `href` ?

Comment: yes we can say that but the href is as i said contained in the page that is loaded

Comment: did you try using an `<iframe>` instead of a `<div>`

Comment: @Babak Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: are you looking for something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adarsmohan76/ux6fLtuv/1/) ? considering the content inside the `#content` as the content from `sendrequestslist.php`. the fiddle doesn't work on ajax functions (i don't know to do ajax in fiddle). but it was working fine in my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using event delegation, `.html()`

```
$("#content").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var html = $(this.href);
  $("#content").html(html)
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by `var html = $(this.href);`?? didn't you get any error in console?

Comment: @AdarshMohan See comments at _"Is expected result for #content html to be replaced by html referenced by a href ?"_ , _"yes we can say that but the href is as i said contained in the page that is loaded"_ . Appears that `href` of `a` elements references fragment identifier of `html` loaded at `$("#content").html(data);` .  `var html = $(this.href);` should select `#elementId` of `a` element `href` . _"didn't you get any error in console?"_ No `.html` or jsfiddle provided , Answer is repsonse to reading descriptions of expected result at comments

Comment: what i said was `$(this.href)` is throwing out errors from jquery. Did you mean `$(this).attr('href')`?

Comment: did you mean something like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adarsmohan76/cdv7gjor/)

Comment: @AdarshMohan No. The `html` would already be within document; not necessary to call `$.ajax()` again

Comment: according to the question, the contents fetched from the `sendrequestslist.php` contains too many links. those links has to opened in a `<div>`

Comment: @AdarshMohan Where does Question text include "too many links" ? Text of Question appears to be _"the problem is when i click on links in the pages it does not open in the same div"_

Comment: ok this code works somehow :  $("#content").on("click", "a", function(e) {
                                                                      e.preventDefault();
                                                                      var html =this.href;
                                                                           $("#content").html(html)
                                                                 }); but it returns the exact Url that i want not its content , i'm trying to get the content with ajax but it does not work , any idea guys

Comment: @Babak _"'i'm trying to get the content with ajax but it does not work"_ Try substituting `$("#content").load(html)` for `$("#content").html(html)`

Comment: @ guest271314 Dude You are AWESOME , Thank you sooooooooooo much man , really appreciate the help